# Confused about Backbone model validating on instantiation

Tags: javascript, validation, backbone.js, coffeescript, instantiation

I'm trying to check if values passed to my model, on instantiation, are empty. If they are, they shouldn't be stored, and shouldn't be retrieved with `model.get('value')`

Model instantiation:

```
# Model
@latLongPicker = new Vamos.Models.LatLongPicker({
  latitude : $('.latlongpicker .data input[name="campaign[latitude]"]').val(),
  longitude : $('.latlongpicker .data input[name="campaign[longitude]"]').val(),
  reach : $('.latlongpicker .data input[name="campaign[reach]"]').val()
}, { validate : true })
```

My model:

```
class Vamos.Models.LatLongPicker extends Backbone.Model

  defaults :
    reach : 5000
    reachMin : 1000
    reachMax : 10000
    lattitude : 52.528239
    longitude : 13.415677

  initialize : ->
    _.bindAll @

    console.log @toJSON()

    console.log @defaults

    console.log @get 'reach'

  validate : (attrs) ->
    if attrs.reach == '' || attrs.reach == 0
      return 'Reach cannot be zero or empty'
    ''
```

I can see that my model is validated, but my console.log tells me that 'reach' is undefined.

I would assume that when my validate method fails, the @get 'reach' would return the default value. What am I missing?

For me the logical way to do it is to validate everything in the model, and not before I pass it to the model.

I might be wrong so I'm asking here to get a better understanding of how I validate properly in Backbone, or if I'm simply doing something fundamentally wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I would assume that when my validate method fails, the @get 'reach' would return the default value. What am I missing?

Failing validation aborts the `set`, leaving the value as it was. What you're missing is that when you validate during instantiation, the previous value for any attribute is `undefined`.

Maybe it's a little counter-intuitive (and might be an issue worth reporting), but during instantiation the defaults and the initial attributes are set and validated in one call, so if validation fails even the defaults aren't set.

Check out the `Backbone.Model` constructor:

```
  var Model = Backbone.Model = function(attributes, options) {
    var defaults;
    var attrs = attributes || {};
    options || (options = {});
    this.cid = _.uniqueId('c');
    this.attributes = {};
    _.extend(this, _.pick(options, modelOptions));
    if (options.parse) attrs = this.parse(attrs, options) || {};
    if (defaults = _.result(this, 'defaults')) {
      attrs = _.defaults({}, attrs, defaults);
    }
    this.set(attrs, options);
    this.changed = {};
    this.initialize.apply(this, arguments);
  };
```

`defaults` is mixed in with the `attributes` that are passed in, and the resulting object (`attrs`) is passed to `set`, rather than `set`ting `defaults` *then* `attributes`.

Comment: Hi Josh. Sorry for the late reply. It makes sense, thanks so much for your help!